# Doubly linked list insertion issues

Tags: c++, pointers, insert, linked-list

I am having issues inserting Nodes in my list so that they would display in order. Here is my function for inserting a Node into the list:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int item)
{
   Node *newNode = new Node;
   newNode -> data = item;

   if(head == NULL)
   {//in case of empty list
      head = tail = newNode;
      newNode -> next = NULL;
      newNode -> previous = NULL;
      ++count;
   } else {

      Node *ptr = head;

      while((ptr && (ptr -> next) != NULL) && (item < (ptr -> data)))
      {//traversing the list to find the correct insertion point
         ptr = ptr -> next;
      }

      if((ptr -> previous) == NULL)
      {//the insertion point is before the head of the list
         newNode -> previous = NULL;
         newNode -> next = ptr;
         ptr -> previous = newNode;
         head = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
      else if((ptr -> next) == NULL) 
      {//end of list insertion
         newNode -> next = NULL;
         newNode -> previous = ptr;
         ptr -> next = newNode;
         tail = newNode;
         ++count;
      } else {//middle of the list insertion
        (ptr -> previous) -> next = newNode;
         newNode -> previous = ptr -> previous;
         newNode -> next = ptr;
         ptr -> previous = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
   }
}
```

The only nodes that are in order are those that are inserted in the head or the tail of the list. When the node has to be inserted in the middle of the list, the order of the nodes is transgressed. Here is what I get when I print out the result from my main()

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList database;

    cout<<"The count is: "<< database.lenght() << endl;

    database.insert(11);
    database.insert(1);
    database.insert(8);
    database.insert(62);
    database.insert(55);
    database.insert(100);
    database.insert(00);
    cout<< endl;

    cout<<"The count is: "<< database.lenght() << endl;

    cout<< endl;
    database.print_forwards();

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
The count is : 0

the count is : 7

 100
 62
 55
 8
 1
 11
 0
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with my insertion function please? Thank you,

Comment: look at check for item < ptr->data. When you have inserted 11 and 1 and then you try to insert 8, then the loop will break at the first iteration itself. That means you will get head (which contains 1). Now your code will insert 8 at the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
if((ptr -> previous) == NULL && item > (ptr -> data))
      {//the insertion point is before the head of the list if value is greater
         newNode -> previous = NULL;
         newNode -> next = ptr;
         ptr -> previous = newNode;
         head = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
else if((ptr -> previous) == NULL && item < (ptr -> data))
      {//the insertion point is after the head of the list if value is smaller
         newNode -> next = NULL;
         newNode -> previous = ptr;
         ptr -> next = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
```

there is a similar bug in your "if((ptr -> next) == NULL)" block. You need to insert in the end only if the number is smaller otherwise its a middle insertion :

```
else if((ptr -> next) == NULL && item < (ptr -> data)) 
      {//end of list insertion
         newNode -> next = NULL;
         newNode -> previous = ptr;
         ptr -> next = newNode;
         tail = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
```

Comment: Your code fixed exactly what was wrong! Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have written the above cycle in a manner that ptr points to the location in the list **before** the item that should be inserted(at least so it seems from the cycle condition). However the case when `(ptr -> previous) == NULL` should check if the new element will become the new head of the list while in fact it checks if the head of the list is the element before our element. You should check if `item < head->data` instead of this check.

Also in the in the middle case you should be working with `ptr->next` and its links not with `ptr->previous`. Try to draw on paper several simple cases - for instance the one you try out in your main and I think you should be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I understand now why my logic was flawed, thanks for helping me out. I was able to make it work correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, since you say that only the head and tail are in ordered you are attempting to have them inserted biggest to smallest? If that's the case it goes wrong immediately. The simplest way to see what's going wrong is to run through your code with your numbers manually. Just follow your code through entering 11, then 1. The 1 gets inserted before 11 because you only do the item < ptr->data check in the while loop, you don't do it again in the if and else.

After 11 is inserted, when try to insert 1, ptr->next is null so the while loop does not run and you go straight to

```
if((ptr -> previous) == NULL)
  {//the insertion point is before the head of the list
     newNode -> previous = NULL;
     newNode -> next = ptr;
     ptr -> previous = newNode;
     head = newNode;
     ++count;
  }
```

Notice no check every takes place for whether to insert it before or after, you just insert the 1 before it. You need an additional check inside the if to check whether the item < ptr->data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your "insert in the middle is not quite right...

```
else {//middle of the list insertion
        (ptr -> previous) -> next = newNode;
         newNode -> previous = ptr -> previous;
         newNode -> next = ptr;
         ptr -> previous = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
```

This inserts the new element just before the pointed to element. I believe you want to insert it after it, somthing like:

```
else {//middle of the list insertion
         newNode->next = ptr->next;
         newNode->next->previous = newNode;
         newNode->previous= ptr;
         ptr->next = newNode;
         ++count;
      }
```